# ClassNotFoundException in nested fragments built by Maven

Tags: android, maven, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-nested-fragment

I have a problem with nested fragments: I have a parent fragment which I use to make a tab for action bar and `SupportMapFragment` to display a map in it, but if I build my project with Maven, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.etaxi.android.driverapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.etaxi.android.driverapp-1, /system/lib]]
```

I'm using official ActionBar support library, and also I'm using `getChildFragmentManager()` everywhere in parent fragment to access `SupportMapFragment` like that:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, seems like the problem was with nested fragments, defined in xml. If add them [programmatically](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding), using `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`, everything works fine.

Just put some `LinearLayout` tag instead of `Fragment` and then put your nested Fragments in it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Follow the image] Check library files under Order and Export tab... Go to properties of project by right click -> then Java Build Path... Follow the above image...